# Web2py app does not see new directories imported by source control

Tags: svn, web2py

I have a web2py server set up. I created an empty app in the admin interface and I used Subversion to bring all the files for that app from the source control repository.

The files end up in the right directories, but when I open the web2py admin I can see all the new controllers, but not the new views. When I try to access the new views via URL I also get an "invalid view" message. I should mention the new views are all inside directories, which I can't see either. New controllers are not inside directories.

Is there some way around this? What is the best practice to use SVN with web2py, if different from what I described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you made the checkout from the repository with insufficient depth, for some reason.

Questions:
 1. How did you call svn to bring your files from the repository to the app folder?
 2. You say your files are in the right place, and then you say the you can't see some of them. Can you describe the file tree in the repository and the resulting file tree in your app folder?